# Struts2 hibernate application not deploying in offline mode

Tags: hibernate, struts2

My application is not allowing me to run in offline mode.  It throws `Error Filter Start` in Tomcat when running Tomcat in offline mode.

What I am thinking is due to dtd present at the header of `struts.xml`, `hibernate.cfg`, `xml,hbm.xml`.
I tried to change the header location to `SYSTEM` by seeing the cache entry in the Eclipse cache section, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

here is a trick for this. you can still use PUBLIC, and download the DTD file, put it into your application and point your hibernate configuration file to the DTD.

**EXAMPLE**

Original:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          “-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN”
          “http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd”>
```

Corrected:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          “-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN”
          “http://localhost/your/app/path/to/the/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd”>
```

Comment: I changed my header to this,,but still the same problem
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          “-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN”
          “http://localhost:8086/pharmacy/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd”>

Comment: try call `localhost:8086/pharmacy/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd` in your browser and to see, if the path is correct. And if you are receiving some exceptions, please post them.

Comment: I tried hitting url from my browser ,and a download option comes.

Comment: have you put the whole url to your configuration? with `http` at the beginning?

Comment: yes i have supplied complete url along with http:// ...and the file gets downloaded from the link.
What i am doing in my application is first i build my project with ant and then extracting the war file by running tomcat and if i disconnect my internet then it shows Error Filter Start.
Three of my file having dtd struts.xml, cfg.xml and hbm.xml(mapping).

Comment: hehe. for sure you not only need dtd for hibernate, you have to get the dtd files for struts configuration. please read your configuration files in detail, then you will find the trick.

Comment: yes i am providing dtd for struts,hibernate and mapping.and using the same url pointing to respective files in my all xml files.